# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'unicode', coords

Tags: python, html, database, unicode

full code is [HERE](https://github.com/stuycs-ml7-projects/YAN-SHAN-PHAN-WU/)

HTML code

```
<input type="hidden" id="Latitude" name="Latitude" value={{Longitude}} />
<input type="hidden" id="Longitude" name="Longitude" value={{Longitude}} />

document.getElementById("Latitude").value  =  position.coords.latitude;
document.getElementById("Longitude").value =  position.coords.longitude;
```

app.py

```
Latitude = request.form['Latitude']
Longitude = request.form['Longitude']

messages = database.returnMessagesinRange(float(Latitude),float(Longitude))
```

database.py

```
def returnMessagesinRange(longitude,latitude):
    allMessages = Messages.find()
    messagesinRange = []
    for current in allMessages:
        if ((current['longitude']-longitude) * (current['longitude']-longitude) + (current['latitude']-latitude)*(current['latitude']-latitude)) <= 1:
            if messagesinRange == None:
                messagesinRange = [current['text']]
            else:
                messagesinRange.append(current['text'])
    return messagesinRange
```

When this is run, i get

```
if ((current['longitude']-longitude) * (current['longitude']-longitude) + (current['latitude']-latitude)*(current['latitude']-latitude)) <= 1:
```

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'unicode'
```

Anyone know why this is happening? thanks.

Comment: Your error cannot match your code: The only subtractions there are `current['longitude']-longitude` and `(current['latitude']-latitude)`. Unless you're calling your function elsewhere, `longitude` and `latitude` are floats, but `current['latitude']` and  `current['longitude']` might be `unicode`s. That would give the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'float'`

Comment: Yep, one of your problems is [here](https://github.com/stuycs-ml7-projects/YAN-SHAN-PHAN-WU/blob/master/app.py#L29)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both the longitude and latitude retrieved from the request and the database are strings (unicode strings) and you are trying to operate on them as if they were numbers.

You should first get the `int` or `float` representation of such strings to be able to operate on them as numbers (using `-`, `*`, etc)

You can do that by creating a `int` or `float` object passing the string as a parameter

```
latitude = int(request.form['Latitude'])
```

or

```
latitude = float(request.form['Latitude'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike in PHP, Python will not auto-convert from string to float. Use:

```
errors = []
try:
    latitude = float(request.form['Latitude'])
except ValueError:
    # do something about invalid input
    latitude = 0.0
    errors.append(u"Invalid input for Latitude.")
```

Answer (score 1):

`current['longitude']` and `longitude` are both `unicode` strings. You need to convert them to `float`s if you plan to subtract them.

Answer (score 0):

ok we did this which works..

```
def returnMessagesinRange(longitude,latitude):
allMessages = Messages.find()
longitude = (eval(str(longitude)))
latitude = (eval(str(latitude)))
messagesinRange = []
for current in allMessages:
    y=eval(str(current['longitude']))
    x=eval(str(current['latitude']))
    if ((longitude-x)*(longitude-x))+((latitude-y)*(latitude-y)) <= 1:
        if messagesinRange == None:
            messagesinRange = [str(current['text'].encode('ascii','ignore'))]
        else:
            messagesinRange.append(str(current['text'].encode('ascii','ignore')))
return messagesinRange
```

finally I can see the ending!